# placing objects perpendicularly on the surface of a sphere that has a wavy surface

Tags: opengl, geometry

So I have a sphere. It rotates around a given axis and changes its surface by a sin * cos function.
I also have a bunck of tracticoids at fix points on the sphere. These objects follow the sphere while moving (including the rotation and the change of the surface). But I can't figure out how to make them always perpendicular to the sphere. I have the ponts where the tracticoid connects to the surface of the sphere and its normal vector. The tracticoids are originally orianted by the z axis. So I tried to make it's axis to the given normal vector but I just can't make it work.

This is where i calculate M transformation matrix and its inverse:

```
virtual void SetModelingTransform(mat4& M, mat4& Minv, vec3 n) {
            M = ScaleMatrix(scale) * RotationMatrix(rotationAngle, rotationAxis) * TranslateMatrix(translation);
            Minv = TranslateMatrix(-translation) * RotationMatrix(-rotationAngle, rotationAxis) * ScaleMatrix(vec3(1 / scale.x, 1 / scale.y, 1 / scale.z));
    }
```

In my draw function I set the values for the transformation.
_M and _Minv are the matrixes of the sphere so the tracticoids are following the sphere, but when I tried to use a rotation matrix, the tracticoids strated moving on the surface of the sphere.
_n is the normal vector that the tracticoid should follow.

```
void Draw(RenderState state, float t, mat4 _M, mat4 _Minv, vec3 _n) {
        SetModelingTransform(M, Minv, _n);
        if (!sphere) {
            state.M = M * _M * RotationMatrix(_n.z, _n);
            state.Minv = Minv * _Minv * RotationMatrix(-_n.z, _n);
        }
        else {
            state.M = M;
            state.Minv = Minv;
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how the surface of the sphere changes. Does it move along some path? Perhaps only the distance to center is changed? Same goes for those "tracticoid" (first time I see that concept), Perhaps you better ask at https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: At the start the surface of the sphere is "flat". by flat i mean it is a prefect sphere. Then the surface starts to became wavy. I dont know how to explain more clearly basically the R of the sphere is multiplied by sin(3 * U + 4 * V) * cos(time) so it starts as a sphere beacmes more wave then less wavy than back to its original sphere form just tu start it over. Then there are tracticoids on the surface which are exacly perpendicular to the sphere and they keep beeing perpendicular as the sphere changes its surface. The shape of the tracticoid stay the same just moves and rotates.

Comment: maybe its just me but what to heck is "tracticoid" cant see anything in my dictionary and on google I only see "tractricoid" and even that without any meaningful description... Also you should add images/sketches of what you have and what you want as its a bit hard to follow your text ... and even more the code ... you are creating matrix for each vertex of your sphere?  You know we can only guess the topology of your surface (how its stored and what are the properties like density etc ...) anyway for perpendicular to surface is a normal enough ... so what is preventing you from computing it?

Answer (score 0):

You said your sphere has an axis of rotation, so you should have a vector `a` aligned with this axis.

Let `P = P(t)` be the point on the sphere at which your object is positioned. You should also have a vector `n = n(t)` perpendicular to the surface of the sphere at point `P=P(t)` for each time-moment `t`. All vectors are interpreted as column-vectors, i.e. 3 x 1 matrices.

Then, form the matrix

```
U[][1] = cross(a, n(t)) / norm(cross(a, n(t)))
U[][3] = n(t) / norm(n(t))  
U[][2] = cross(U[][3], U[][1])
```

where for each `j=1,2,3` `U[][j]` is a 3 x 1 vector column. Then

```
U(t) = [ U[][1], U[][2], U[][3] ]
```

is a 3 x 3 orthogonal matrix (i.e. it is a 3D rotation around the origin)

For each moment of time `t` calculate the matrix

```
M(t) = U(t) * U(0)^T
```

where `^T` is the matrix transposition.

The final transformation that rotates your object from its original position to its position at time `t` should be

```
X(t) = P(t) + M(t)*(X - P(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your explanations, but here I go.

You have a sphere with a wavy surface. This means that each point on the surface changes its distance to the center of the sphere, like a piece of wood on a wave in the sea changes its distance to the bottom of the sea at that position.

We can tell that the radious `R` of the sphere is variable at each point/time case.

Now you have a tracticoid (what's a tracticoid?). I'll take it as some object floating on the wave, and following the sphere movements.

Then it seems you're asking as how to make the tracticoid follows both wavy surface and sphere movements.

Well. If we define each movement ("transformation") by a 4x4 matrix it all reduces to combine in the proper order those matrices.

There are some good OpenGL tutorials that teach you about transformations, and how to combine them. See, for example, [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com).

To your case, there are several transformations to use.

The sphere spins. You need a rotation matrix, let's call it `MSR` (matrix sphere rotation) and an axis of rotation, `ASR`. If the sphere also translates then also a `MST` is needed.

The surface waves, with some function `f(lat, long, time)` which calculates for those parameters the increment (signed) of the radious. So, `Ri = R + f(la,lo,ti)`

For the tracticoid, I guess you have some triangles that define a tracticoid. I also guess those triangles are expressed in a  "local" coordinates system whose origin is the center of the tracticoid. Your issue comes when you have to position and rotate the tracticoid, right?

You have two options. The first is to rotate the tracticoid to make if aim  perpendicular to the sphere and then translate it to follow the sphere rotation. While perfect mathematically correct, I find this option some complicated.

The best option is to make the tracticoid to rotate and translate exactly as the sphere, as if both would share the same origin, the center of the sphere. And then translate it to its current position.

First part is quite easy: The matrix that defines such transformation is `M= MST * MSR`, if you use the typical OpenGL axis convention, otherwise you need to swap their order. This `M` is the common part for all objects (sphere & tracticoids).

The second part requires you have a vector `Vn` that defines the point in the surface, related to the center of the sphere. You should be able to calculate it with the parameters latitude, longitude and the `R` obtained by `f()` above, plus the size/2 of the tracticoid (distance from its center to the point where it touches the wave). Use the components of `Vn` to build a [translation matrix](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/) `MTT`

And now, just get the resultant transformation to use with every vertex of the tracticoid: `Mt = MTT * M = MTT * MST * MSR`

To render the scene you need other two matrices, for the camera (`MV`) and for the projection (`MP`). While `Mt` is for each tracticoid, `MV` and `MP` are the same for all objects, including the sphere itself.